# The relative h-principle and extension problems

Tags: symplectic-topology, h-principle

As a beginner for h-principles, I want to know why the relative
h-principle cannot imply a positive solution to the problems for
extending symplectic structures.

The following is a relative h-principle theorem in Y. Eliashberg and
N.Mishachev's book 'Introduction to the h-principle'.

Theorem. Let $R\subset X^{(r)}$ be an open $DiffV$-differential
relation over an open manifold $V$. Let $B\subset V$ be a closed
subset such that each connected component of the complement
$V\backslash B$ has an exit to $\infty$. Then the relative
parametric h-principle holds for $R$ and the pair (V,B).

The book also presents the following extension problem.

Problem. Let $\omega$ be a symplectic form near $\partial D^{2n}$,
$n>1$, which extends to $D^{2n}$ as a non-degenerate form and which
satisfies the positivity condition. Does it extend to $D^{2n}$ as a
symplectic form?

In the book it says that the answer to the problem above is negative
in all dimensions. But I think the relative h-principle may imply a
positive answer of the extension problem above, just as the
application of Gromov's h-principle to the existence of the
symplectic structure on open 2n-manifolds. Let $V=D^{2n}$ and $B=\partial D^{2n}$ in the Theorem, this will be done.I don't know what's wrong
with my thought.

Comment: There are no exits to $\infty$ in the closed disc.